# bulma not working with vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, bulma

I started a project with vue-cli, then I run

```
npm bulma install
```

and imported bulma in my App.vue

```
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass";
@import '../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables.sass'
```

But I am using their classes and do not work.

```
<div class="columns">
<div class="column">1</div>
<div class="column">2</div>
<div class="column">3</div>
<div class="column">4</div>
<div class="column">5</div>
```

Comment: Did you tried to use Vue-Bulma components? Here they are: https://github.com/vue-bulma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were two problems,

I am using sass, and I was not defining it on style tag

```
<style lang="sass">
```

And I was missing sass-loader

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. This helped me finish getting it loaded https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper/issues/104